# Should tags be written in the plural or singular form?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that many of our popular tags are currently written in the plural form.

[substitutes](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substitutes) [micronutrients](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/micronutrients) [dairy-products](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dairy-products) [sports](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports) [supplements](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supplements) [fats](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fats)

This came to my attention while I was thinking about tag wikis and excerpts. I was looking at [tags on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/tags) for examples of how they write tag wikis, and I noticed that most of their tags are written in the singular.

[sql-server](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) [vpn](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vpn) [backup](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup) [firewall](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firewall) [web-server](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-server) [proxy](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proxy) [ssl-certificate](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssl-certificate) [domain](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain)

Why have we ended up with many tags in the plural case? Do we prefer it this way, or is it a problem? This has been discussed before on the main [StackExchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6752/merge-singular-and-plural-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1) and it seems that they ended up preferring the singular case anywhere it worked.