# Do you like the idea of an [unresolved] tag on Meta?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

I'm considering introducing a new tag, [unresolved](/questions/tagged/unresolved), for questions here on Meta that still require some kind of action or decision.

#### Meta tags, only on Meta

This would be what Jeff Atwood calls a meta tag, and vigorously decried in his 2010 blog post [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). Meta tags never work for other sites...  [but it might work for us](https://www.quotes.net/show-quote/5722). When Jeff wrote about the pain of meta tags, it was barely a year after the first StackOverflow Meta site was launched, and I don't think he had considered their use in this context.

Basically, I believe that meta tags **do** work well, but only on meta sites. As evidence I'll point to a few of the other meta tags that are already in use: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), [featured](/questions/tagged/featured).

#### Motivation

- This tag would make it easier for people engaged in the site to discover the current issues that require feedback or action.
- It would help to prevent discussions from getting buried in the sands of time and never acted on.
- The discussion pops to the top of Meta once again as it reaches a conclusion, helping to spread the message about a decision or action.

#### Rejected Alternatives

- Marking answers as [accepted](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) doesn't work very well, because responsibility falls on a single person and the community cannot collaborate to help maintain the list of what is unresolved. And some questions are really announcements, and they will never receive an answer that can be accepted.
- If the tag was instead framed in the positive, like [resolved](/questions/tagged/resolved), it would accumulate on all of the questions and end up being the most-used tag on the Meta site. That upsets the balance of tags and makes tags less useful.
- [Bumping questions](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/276/5) is just really unpleasant.

Comment: Alternately, a [meta-tag:needs-moderator] tag might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I support introduction of an [unresolved](/questions/tagged/unresolved) tag and its application to these questions:

- [Let's rename the [raw] tag to [rawfood-diet]](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/273/1236)
- [Should tags be written in the plural or singular form?](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/277/1236)
- [Do you like the idea of an [unresolved] tag on Meta?](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/326/1236)
- [Add related sites on StackExchange to our FAQ for on-topic questions](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/257/1236)
- [Is the [food] tag too greedy, or should it eat even more?](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/245/1236)